# accurate trig functions in java

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I am working in java with astronomical equations. I need to do some programming with sin and cos functions. I am getting wrong values and rounding errors that are causing problems with the results.

one specific example that is way off:

```
 Dec=Math.atan(Math.tan(Eps)*Math.sin(RA));
```

for the values, using degrees, Eps=23.440 & RA=312.5175, i should get the answer -17.7223
but, instead i get

```
 Dec=0.6587619787704015
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround or a good math library for these math functions? Should I be doing this in C and passing the results?  Actually, C also gives me some errors with accuracy.

i'm using degrees.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using radians or degrees?

Comment: matlab would probably do it. but, s/w eng. wise, i can't use it.  it does not run on the target equipment.  ...  what is "R"? ... i used degrees in all my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigonometry in Java and many other languages is based on radians instead of degrees. You may know that

```
180 degrees = PI = 3.1415... radians.
```

so if we divide all sides by 180 we will get

```
1 degree = (3.1415.../180) radians
^^^^^^^^
```

same way if we divide it by 3.1415... we will get

```
(180/3.1415...) degrees = 1 radian 
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

But you don't have to do the calculations yourself. You can use built-in methods

- `Math.toRadians(degrees)`
- `Math.toDegrees(radians)`

like

```
double Eps = 23.440;
double RA = 312.5175;
double EpsRad = Math.toRadians(Eps);
double RARad = Math.toRadians(RA);
double tmp1 = Math.tan(EpsRad);
double tmp2 = Math.sin(RARad);
double result = Math.atan(tmp1 * tmp2);

System.out.println("in radians: " + result); //-0.30931302106018527
System.out.println("in degrees: " + Math.toDegrees(result));//-17.722330655189765
```

or inline them like

```
System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math
        .toRadians(Eps))) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(RA))));//-17.722330655189765
```

Answer (score 7):

Those maths methods take radians, not degrees.

I guess that `RA=312.5175` is interpred as `312.5175 % (2*Pi)` radians.

Comment: This can't be upvoted enough. This is a very common mistake people make. I don't know any programming languages that use degrees.

Comment: thanks!  i'll give it a shot.  don't understand why i've been getting almost correct answers all along though.  fluke of choice of numbers maybe.

Comment: No, you haven't.  And every language that I know uses radians.

Comment: yeah, that fixed it.  but, funny, the wrong answers were very close.  thought they were just rounding errors.